# How to add GeoServer WMS layer to Mapbox GL API?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have been using GeoServer WMS layers with OpenLayers 3 and it is working well.
Below is the code how I have used to add my GeoServer WMS layer to the Mapbox GL API:

```
   var mapOptions: MapboxOptions = {
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
  zoom: 17.5,
  center: [0.5500863948437313, 53.229982583617584],
  pitch: 60
}

this.mapInstance = new Map(options);
var layerConfig: mapboxgl.Layer = {
  'id': 'wms-test-layer',
  'type': 'raster',
  'source': {
    'type': 'raster',
    'tiles': [
      'https://geoserver.visur.io/geoserver/****/wms?BBOX={bbox-epsg-3857}&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&CRS=EPSG:3857&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&LAYERS=tourmalineqa:GasWell&FORMAT=image/png'
    ],
    'tileSize': 256
  },
  'paint': {}
}

this.mapInstance.addLayer(layerConfig)
```

same with OpenLayers is working fine but in Mapbox GL API I am getting below error

> ERROR Error: Style is not done a the loading
>       at i._checkLoaded (mapbox-gl.js:33)
>       at i.addLayer (mapbox-gl.js:33)
>       at r.addLayer (mapbox-gl.js:33)
>       at MapComponent.push../src/app/map/map.component.ts.MapComponent.addWmsLayer (map.component.ts:363)

**LOOKS like the official sample itself is not loading as their services are no longer available [Mapbox-gl WMS sample](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/wms/)**

Comment: A style parameter is required for a GetMap request, unless you supply an SLD or SLD_BODY parameter, in which case it is optional but you don't seem to be supplying one ~ what request gets generated?